# Using inclusion_tag decorater with dynamic template

Tags: django, django-templates, templatetags

Here is the standard inclusion tag:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('results.html')
def show_results(poll):
...
```

I'd like to know if is it possible to use an inclusion tag, defining dynamically the template tag. Example:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('%s.html' % PATH)
def show_results(poll, PATH):
 ...
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible, because that's not how decorators (or indeed Python functions generally) work. Parameters are evaluated when the module is first imported.

You'd need to write a proper custom tag, without using the `inclusion_tag` shortcut decorator. This actually isn't all that hard, the documentation shows you how.